# How to make an error reportable in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, reporting, guzzle

I have a problem with my api, my api connects to different external apis, it uses guzzle to make requests, I would like that every 500 status error displayed for those external apis to be reportable, so I could send an alert using sentry, I have this code:

**app\Exceptions\Handler.php**

```
 public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
         ///dd('is reportable');

            if (app()->bound('sentry') && config('app.env') === 'production') {
                app('sentry')->captureException($e);
            }
        });
    }
```

In my local environment the .env file is set like this:

```
 APP_NAME=App
    APP_ENV=production
    APP_KEY=base64:lkjslkdjflkjlksdfb5uk=
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_URL=http://localhost
....
```

I did this to make some tests to see if everything is working fine, but it is not working.
I disable the mysql and I was able to trigger the alert, but I would like to trigger the alert for all 500 errors that those apis return. For example, if I am making a request to a external server using guzzle and it get this 500 status error:

```
{
    "message": "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https:\/\/invalid url' : failed to load external entity \"https:\/\/invalid\"\n",
    "exception": "SoapFault",
    "file": "/path/file.php",
    "line": 100,
    "trace": [
        {
```

I should be able to trigger the alert but I noticed that is not entering to this method

```
$this->reportable(
```

What can I do?

Comment: Catch exception from guzzle and use report() function.

Comment: umm, that could be a good idea, the problem is I have a plenty of external api requests for different services, I would need to catch the exception for every request

Comment: Make a service whom make requests - and implement request in one place.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, all exceptions pass through a file that can be found here: app/Exceptions/Handler.php.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
       Log::info($e->getMessage());
    });
}
```

there will be a new log created in storage/logs/laravel.log that will contain the following message

looks like this

```
[2022-08-03 08:07:56] local.INFO: Undefined variable $variableMissing
```

**Useful Error Logging with Honeybadger**

Installing Honeybadger is simple and easy, so please head over to the Honeybadger Laravel Docs and follow the step-by-step guide to install it. You will notice that all you need to do is install the composer dependency and set up the reportable callback:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        if (app()->bound('honeybadger')) {
            app('honeybadger')->notify($e, app('request'));
        }
    });
}
```

After installing the Honeybadger composer dependency, run the following:

```
php artisan honeybadger:install your-project-api-key
```

Laravel will now send all error data to Honeybadger instead of a log file, which is much easier and cleaner to work with.

**Creating Custom Exceptions**

To Recap, we have shown what is considered an error in Laravel, how to edit the default pages, and how to hook into the exceptions that are thrown. However, let's take this tutorial a step further and build a custom exception.

Custom exceptions can be used for a number of purposes. The one I find most useful is to provide context for which area of the application I need to look into. For this simple use case and demo purposes, we’ll name our exception FailedToLoadHomePage and fire this if we are unable to render our home-page view for whatever reason.

Fire up that terminal and let's get started:

```
php artisan make: exception FailedToLoadHomePage
```

This will create a new class for us here app/Exceptions/FailedToLoadHomePage.php, and this class contains the following boilerplate:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class FailedToLoadHomePage extends Exception
{
    //
}
```

Now what we want to do is return to our route file and throw this exception when something goes wrong.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    try {
        return view('welcome', [
            'data' => $variableMissing
        ]);
    } catch (Throwable $exception) {
        throw new FailedToLoadHomePage($exception->getMessage());
    }
});
```